# Number of objects in a 3D image

Tags: python, c++, image-processing, recursion

I am trying to calculate the number of objects in a 3D image, and I found this code in Python:

```
def count_objects(image):
    width, height = len(image[0]), len(image)
    objects_members = [(x, y) for x in range(width) for y in range(height) if image[y][x] == 1]
    objects_count = 0
    while objects_members != []:
       remove_object(objects_members, objects_members.pop(0))
       objects_count += 1
    return objects_count

def remove_object(objects_members, start_point):
    x, y = start_point
    connex = [(x - 1, y), (x, y - 1),
              (x + 1, y), (x, y + 1)]
    for point in connex:
        try:
            objects_members.remove(point)
            remove_object(objects_members, point)
        except ValueError:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    image = []
    while True:
        line = input()
        if line == "":
            break
        image.append([int(pixel) for pixel in line])
    print(count_objects(image))
```

This method identifies the pixels belonging to an object (set to 1) and then removes one, its neighbors and the neighbors of its neighbors (deletes an object) and the operation is repeated until all have been removed.

I tried to convert this code in c++, but my recursive function doesn't seem to stop. Here is my code (RemoveObject function):

```
void RemoveObject(vector<int> Vector, int start_point)
{
    int     *IndexNeighbor;
    unsigned char     *Neighbor;
    Neighbor=Neighborhood26(Image, start_point); //26-Connex neighborhood
    IndexNeighbor=IndexNeighborhood26(start_point);// the index of 26-Connex neighborhood
    vector<int> Connex;
    for(int i=0; i<26;i++)
    {
        bool isIN=false;
        if((int)Neighbor[i]==1)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<Vector.size();k++)
            {if(IndexNeighbor[i]==Vector[k]){isIN=true;}}   
         } 
        if(isIN==true){Connex.push_back(IndexNeighbor[i]);}
    }

    if(Connex.size()==0){cout<<"Vector empty"<<endl;}
    else
    {
        for(int j=0; j<Connex.size(); j++)
        {
            Vector.erase(std::remove(Vector.begin(), Vector.end(), Connex[j]), Vector.end());
            RemoveObject(Vector, Connex[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out the mistake that I am making?

Thank you

Comment: I suspect you want to pass `Vector` by reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. But the problem now is that the function is causing stackoverflow, when i try it on a small 3D image it works fine, but when I try it on something a little bit larger it causes stack overflow. Is there any solution??